# How to generate a list of datas from a table with more y-values

Tags: import, excel

I try to create a list of data on which I can perfrom a function. But I have problems in getting the data from my Excel sheet.
My Excel sheet looks like this:

```
      x1 y[1,1] y[1,2] y[1,3] y[1,4] .... y[1,200]
      x2 y[2,1] y[2,2] y[2,3] y[2,4] .... y[2,200]
      ...
      xn ..
```

now I would like to get a list

```
      { {data1}, {data2}, {data3}, ... {data200}}
```

where

```
      data1 = {{x1,y[1,1]},{x2,y[2,1]},..}
      and 
      data2 = {{x1,y[1,2]},{x2,y[2,2]},..}
      and so on
```

Can anyone give me an advice how to do it?
Thanks a lot
Walter

Comment: Did you check `Import` (and possibly the `"Table"` option)?

Comment: @anderstood thanks, but how can I make the list by mapping it with a rule. The x value is the first column and always the same for the different y-values, which are in separate columns

Comment: If you managed to import the data, then your question is about rearranging the imported list and you should probably rewrite your question which is not related to importing nor excel.

Comment: @anderstood thanks I found it: `Table[{s[[i, 1]], s[[1, j]]}, {i, 1, Length[s]}, {j, 2,   Length[First@s]}] '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question. Say you have imported the following structure:

```
 import = {{x1, y[1, 1], y[1, 2], y[1, 3]}, {x2, y[2, 1], y[2, 2], y[2, 3]}}
```

Then, it would probably be more appropriate to save new lists in `data[1]`, `data[2]`, etc. rather than `data1`, `data2`, etc. This is how it could be done:

```
Table[data[i - 1] = 
   Transpose@{import[[All, 1]], import[[All, i]]}, {i, 2, Length@Transpose@import}]
```

Then:

```
 data[1] (* {{x1, y[1, 1]}, {x2, y[2, 1]}} *)
 data[2] (* {{x1, y[1, 2]}, {x2, y[2, 2]}} *)
```

If you really need `data1`, `data2`, etc. let me know and I'll add a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution is much more sophisticated

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair Still, you can improve your question to help future users.

Answer (score 3):

Given @anderstood's data structure, another way, if you really want to learn about some [List Manipulation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html) functions:

```
data = Transpose[Map[Thread[List[First[#], Rest[#]]&, import]]
```

The trick here is using `List[...]` as the function getting threaded between the `First` element and the list of the `Rest` of the elements. `Map` is just the iteration through each row.

Also, this would normally be written like this, where `/@` is infix shorthand for `Map`:

```
data = Thread[{First[#], Rest[#]}]& /@ import // Transpose
```

Comment: I am not home to test this for syntax issues, so please help out and correct me :^) I'll check it myself later.

Comment: I tested, I think you mean `data = Transpose@Map[Thread[List[First[#], Rest[#]]] &, import]` (added one closing bracket + `Transpose`). As per the second line, I think you should add `// Transpose` afterwards.

Comment: Ah, thank you @anderson! Will fix.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Thanks that was I was wanted to learn, and now I can apply my function to this list of datas, I think by `f @@@ {data}`